# Reading the JSON response from the Giphy

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, giphy

I am trying to read the results from a $.getJSON() request.

The results are here...

http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=funny+cat&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=1&offset=0

I am trying to get the value of bitly_gif_url using

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
            console.log(data[index].bitly_gif_url);
        });
```

But it just returns undefined.
I have tried different ways to get to the data but i am struggle and kindly request any suggestions thanks

Comment: I guess you need `$.each(data.data, ...)`.

Comment: thank you ... that set me on the right track...
the full solution is .... 

$.each(data.data, function(index) {

  console.log(data.data[index].bitly_gif_url)

        });

Answer (score 0):

If your domain is not http://api.giphy.com, then you are trying to make a cross-domain Ajax request.
Cross-domain requests are prohibited by most browsers.
Please read more at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ -> crossDomain

Comment: i thought this was dependent on the other server settings, and usually if i come across this issue i see an error message, also i can actually output the console.log(data) i just cant exact the bitly_gif_url... but thanks for your suggestion